# How Can I Clear The Selected Field In Input Using Angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How Can I clear selected filed in input element,[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pwlZnMFG03TzOjrDzSfB?p=preview)

- Look at my plunker for reference.
- I have used Start date and End date inputs , which is used to filter the `Due_date`. If we select Start Date like:- `16-09-2016` the data's has filtering in the table.
- In that date input has one `X` `close` button to clear the field, but which is not working, if we click that `x` clear button the table is showing like empty data's.
- What we excatly looking for , if we click that `x` clear button it's should to be clear selected fileds and need to display all datas in table ....like we have given the exaple plunker is here :- http://plnkr.co/edit/QuJvCXFpKbwVd0OlkHZ2?p=preview  for this plunker `x` clear button is working perfectly, I don't where I made a mistake,
- Please help us.

**My controller for daterange filter:-**

```
 .filter("myfilter", function() {
     return function(items, from, to) {
       var df = from;
         var dt =to;
           var result = [];   
             console.log(to);
            for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
           var date = moment(items[i].invoice_date);
          date.add(items[i].terms,'d');
         var tf = date;
       if (date.isAfter(moment(from)) && date.isBefore(moment(to)))  {
                    result.push(items[i]);
                }
            }   
             //console.log(items);
            return result;
      };
    });
```

**My html :-**

```
 <input type="date" class="form-control" name="from" ng-model="from">

  <input type="date" class="form-control" name="to" ng-model="to">
```

**Filter for daterange:-**

```
   <tr ng-repeat="data in  record | myfilter:from:to">

    <td> {{addDays(data.invoice_date,data.terms) | date:'yyyy-MM-dd'}}</td>

    </tr>
```

I have created my plunker to reference :- [My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/pwlZnMFG03TzOjrDzSfB?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add date validation in your filter

```
  app.filter("myfilter", function() {
  return function(items, from, to) {
  if(from.length!=0 && to.length!=0)
  {
     var df = from;
     var dt =to;
     var result = [];   
    console.log(to);
    for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++){
        var date = moment(items[i].invoice_date);
        date.add(items[i].terms,'d');
        var tf = date;
        if (date.isAfter(moment(from)) && date.isBefore(moment(to)))  {
            result.push(items[i]);
        }
      }   
     //console.log(items);
      return result;
   }else
 {

   return items;
 }
};
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the filter condition to:

`if (date.isAfter(moment(from)) || from == null && date.isBefore(moment(to)) || to == null)`

This will remove the date constraint if `from` or `to` is not set.

[Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/BiUB132CBgNNIxGqNsH7?p=preview)

---

Edit: Please add brackets like this:

```
if ((date.isAfter(moment(from)) || from == null) && 
    (date.isBefore(moment(to)) || to == null))  {
    //...
}
```

[Updated Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/bVrOlAB5gvQNoVrX078X?p=preview)

Comment: thank you for your valuable answer, We can able to clear the `start date`, but the `end date` is not filtering bcoz of your code changes, so can you please check and update the plunker.... thanks....

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Please see the edited answer and the updated Plunkr.

Comment: thank you so much for the perfect answer, I will check this in my local host and update you asap.... thanks